# how to communicate from angular's controller to other modules in node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, node-webkit

I got an angularJS' controller used in node-webkit app, how to call db.js ' save_db from angular's controller? code as follow, thanks:

```
angular.module('clk.controllers', [])
.controller('homeCtrl', ["$scope",function ($scope) {
  $scope.post_it = function(tm) {

  }
}])

db.js
var db = mongo.db(db_connection)
var users = db.collection('users')

exports.save_db = function (rec, cb) {
  users.insert(rec, {
   safe: true
}, function (err, records) {
    cb(null, '')
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you would simply require your db.js file and call the Node library as per usual e.g.

```
var db = require('./db.js');
var app = angular.module('clk.controllers', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.post_it = function(tm) {
        db.save_db(tm, function () {
            console.log('record added');
        });
    };
}]);
```